# How do I delete all the arrays and only show the message?

Tags: php

I'm making a timeline-alike widget but I'm stuck at the `fetchAll()` function.

```
<?php
require('./dbconfig.php');
$userid = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$query = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT bericht FROM tijdlijn WHERE auteurid=:uid");
$query->execute(array(':uid' => $userid));

$tijdlijn=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r ($tijdlijn[1]);

?>
```

which results in this:

```
Array ( [bericht] => Dit is een 2de test )
```

I just want 'Dit is een 2de test' to show up, not all the other stuff.

I also want to show all the messages that are from the same author. I have a script that only shows the messages to the author.

Answer (score 0):

The array is 2-dimensional, you also need to specify the second index or it will print the entire second dimension.

```
print_r ($tijdlijn[1]['bericht']);
```

The array it's first index is the row # of the output and the second index is the column name.